# Help me check my Automata from given Grammar

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata

My update :

Find Automata for $G = (V, T, S, P)$, where $V = [0, 1, S, A, B]$ and $T = [0,1]$ and $P = \{ S -> 1B, S->0, A->1A, A->0B, A->1, A->0, B->1\}$

Please look at question C

[image]

My answer ( c ) :

[image]

My question :

1. Did i do it (c) right?
2. As you can see, there are no way to get to S3 (A), so that can i cut down the S3 (A) from the automata?

Comment: Note: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: @FrenzyLi thanks, i will update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your observation is correct. State $s_3$ is not needed.

Also, the answer to $b)$ is not correct as it recognizes  the strings $10$, $11$ which are not in the language.